# Prevent user to use binary operators defined in a new type

Tags: haskell

I'm currently trying to define multivariate polynomials over a field in Haskell ([work in progress](https://github.com/stla/mpolynomials)). I have as a starting point:

```haskell
data Polynomial a = Zero
                  | M (Monomial a)
                  | Polynomial a :+: Polynomial a
                  | Polynomial a :*: Polynomial a
                    deriving (Show)
```

Is it possible to prevent the user to use the binary operators `:+:` and `:*:`? I'd like, because I define the addition and the multiplication later, which not only perform the operation but also put the result in canonical form (sum of monomials with distinct powers), and I would like that the user can only use these operations.

I would bet that's not possible if one exports the `Polynomial` type, but maybe the brilliant minds here have a trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export the `Polynomial` type without exporting its constructors.

```
module Foo(Polynomial()) where
```

would do this.

Comment: Yes, that's what I just find! But one needs the parentheses: **Polynomial()** otherwise I can't do **Polynomial Double** for example. The key point is to not export **Polynomial(..)**, with the two periods.